# Why is this current sensing resistor called "Wirewound"?

Tags: resistors, shunt

I recently found a current sensing resistor. In the [datasheet for Vishay's SR series](http://www.vishay.com/docs/31067/sr.pdf), this resistor is titled "Wirewound Resistor...". Is this type of current shunt really a wirewound type, but not a solid metal internal?

[image]

Comment: It could be because its not from a ceramic material like standard resistors. It is made from a piece of wire therefore wire wound.

Comment: I think it simply inhabits the range of values, power dissipations, etc that are traditionally associated with wirewound resistors. Also it *is*  a half turn of unusually shaped wire... So rather than invent a new category for it, fit it into the best existing one.

Comment: @Brian They already have a category called "Power Metal Strip / Metal Element". See my answer below.

Comment: It is not unknown for documentation to lag behind a bit, and this datasheet is from 2011. Only last year I saw an EPCOS datasheet, presumably written shortly after the merger of Siemens passive components with Matsushita's, that referred to the previous short-lived name... *cough* S&M Components.

Comment: @Brian: Do you mean there is no "wirewound" internal, and it *is* a solid metal one?

Comment: Yes, given the resistance values in the datasheet.

Comment: @Brian: "Given the resistance values", do you mean some resistance value can only be achieved by using solid metal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why it's called Wirewound, but it says clearly in the datasheet:

> • All welded construction
>
> • Solid metal nickel-chrome or copper-nickel alloy resistive element

I found [this document](http://www.vishay.com/docs/49873/49873_sg2113.pdf) on the SR product page and it looks like Vishay are contradicting themselves:

[image]